# Unwanted spacing under buttons in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding websites and currently doing an assignment.

My issue is that when mousing over my navigation bar, the hover color does not fully cover the entire item. How do I solve this? Is it occurring due to my logo?

[image: Like so...]

My html code:

```css
.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(134, 35, 35);
  font-family: Megrim, cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* floats navigation buttons to the right */

.naviright {
  float: right;
}


/*makes elements start from the left*/

.navigation li {
  float: left;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

.navigation li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigation li a:hover:active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


/*TopNav End*/


/*logo*/

#logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#logoname {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li id="logo"><img src="images\logo.svg"></li>
    <li id="logoname"><a>Stationery Haven</a></li>
    <div class="naviright">
      <li><a href="index3.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </div>`enter code here`
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That is correct. Your image with padding/margin makes a space

Comment: alright, thanks! i'll go look into it:)

Comment: It is possible to create jsfiddle? At first ensure that nav height not exceeding your link item height due to logo. Suppose if your nav height 40px but your link item height is 38px or something then it should happen. Another point is ensure that no bottom padding margin for ul, li or link itself.

Comment: @Hanif I made a snippet for them. Click full screen to see it work

Answer (score 0):

Add line-height to li a

```
.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height:22px;
}
```

```css
.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(134, 35, 35);
  font-family: Megrim, cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* floats navigation buttons to the right */

.naviright {
  float: right;
}


/*makes elements start from the left*/

.navigation li {
  float: left;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height:22px;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

.navigation li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigation li a:hover:active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


/*TopNav End*/


/*logo*/

#logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#logoname {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li id="logo"><img src="images\logo.svg"></li>
    <li id="logoname"><a>Stationery Haven</a></li>
    <div class="naviright">
      <li><a href="index3.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </div>`enter code here`
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I reviewed you code I think if you add or change following css code then it will be work for you:

```
#logo {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 4px; // Changed here 5px to 4px
 padding-top: 2px;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  line-height: 22px; // Logo test font-size: 20px; so this line need to be added
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You could solve this by increasing the size of

`.naviright li a {font-size: 20px;}`

2) or you could just give the line-height to -

`.navigation li a {line-height: 22px;}`

Here is the flex based solution I've tried [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/dpq6edL1/)